# Manually switch from ART to Dalvik

Tags: adb, root-access, recovery-mode, dalvik, art

I wanted to try out the new ART runtime, but didn't realize my custom ROM doesn't support it. So now I am getting recurring Force Closed messages after booting, and  can't get through to the settings menu to switch back to Dalvik. So before I wipe everything and spend hours setting up my phone from scratch, is there a way to manually change back to Dalvik from the recovery menu? I think there should be a flag somewhere, that instructs Android to do the 'recompile' after a reboot.

Via the recovery menu, I have full root access over a adb shell and can mount all filesystems.

Comment: I had a problem with ART on a stock 4.4.4 ROM.  A few days after switching from dalvik, I was stuck in a boot loop with adb logcat showing a lot of crash errors including `art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Runtime aborting...  Switching back to dalvik, I had to reboot into recovery and use the echo command to switch back to dalvik. That fixed the problem

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just did this!

`/data/property/persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib` is a textfile containing one of two values: 'libart.so' or 'libdvm.so'. You can change from ART to Dalvik simply by editing this file.

Ex: adb shell 'echo libdvm.so >/data/property/persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib'

Comment: FWIW, doing "setprop persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib libdvm.so" would have the same effect -- the "persist" properties are persisted by writing them to a file.

Comment: When this happened to me, I had no adb shell access while Android was running. However, I was able to reboot into ClockworkMod Recovery, clear my cache partition and dalvik cache to free up some flash storage space, mount my /data partition, and then (finally) use adb shell as described in this answer. Whew!

Comment: I tried this on Android 5.0.1 (Omega V28) on my Galaxy S4 GT-I9500. The file was called `/data/property/persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2` in my case. After rebooting it somehow reverted to "libart.so". Any idea why it's doing that and how to change it permanently?

Comment: This happened even when I changed the file contents via adb shell in recovery. So it's not getting overwritten on shutdown, but on boot, it seems.